# Generate RSA key given modulus, public exponent and prime1

Tags: openssl, rsa, private-key

So I have to generate a private key (RSA) given its bit length, the modulus, the first prime and the public exponent.

The problem is that I have the modulus and prime1 in hexadecimal pairs. I've tried doing it manually but the number gets really long (obviously). I've also tried to use the `openssl genpkey` but for RSA it doesn't have the parameters I'd need.

Does someone know any way to do it or I will have to operate manually in hex/binary?

Comment: You're going to have to write a program to do it. The openssl command line tools are not going to do this for you.

Comment: @GregS - I think its easier than that (I read it like you first time). He has the modulus `n` and `p`. He only needs to solve for `q`. With `p`, `q` and `e`, he can efficiently compute `d`. And then use the CRT to recover the other RSA private key parameters, like `dp`, `dq` and `q-inv`. Finally, he can stuff it in a `RSA*`. Viola!

Comment: @jww yeah, but I 3 pairs of hex values of the p where missing, so I had to "guess" them. I already solved it, but thanks for the time anyway!

Answer (score -1):

As James K Polk comments on the question, openssl doesn't support generating keys in this manner. You'll have to write a program yourself to do this.

For example, the following Java code would work. You'll need to handle the exceptions as well.

```
BigInteger modulus = /* modulus here */;
BigInteger exponent = /* exponent here */;
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
keyFactory.generatePrivate(new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, exponent));
```